# Getting an undefinded function error when calling file_get_contents() using php version 7.4.33

Tags: function, runtime-error, undefined

Not much more to report?? I am trying to read/write a simple one line file. I can use file_put_contents() in a similar program and it works but when I try to use file_get_contents() it gives me an undefined function error?? I get the the error on the hosting site which uses php version 7.4.33 and on the localhost xamp that reports using 7.3.5.

code snippets

````
Your system doesn't allow me to enter my code?? 
It gives me an error about improperly formatted code??

Where is the toolbar for tabbing by 4 spaces?```

Tried to read one line file with file_get_contents() and got an 'undefined function' error.
````

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, sorry, I found that I had somehow inserted a odd char just before typing in the file_get_contents()?? It had an ord value of 194. It appeared to be just a blank. Don't understand how the system included that strange character in the file_get_contents().

Again sorry. Just a rookie coder